# Display specific values from JSON response in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, jquery-filter

I have the following ajax function:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    dataType: 'json',
    callback: null,
    url: urlLocation,
    data: saveImage,
    success: function(response){
        $(".response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, '&nbsp').replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
        $(".response").css('font-family', 'Knowledge');
    },
    error: function (data) {
    $(".share-link").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><p>Couldn't send photo: <b>"+ imageid.value + "</b></p></div>");
    }
});
```

that sends back a response

```
{
 "status": {
  "code": 200,
  "description": "OK"
 },
 "entity": {
  "entityType": "EntityMap",
  "entryKeyType": "Orientation",
  "entryValueType": "ImageResource",
  "entries": {
   "SQUARE": {
    "uri": "http://www.url.com/image-file",
    "orientation": "SQUARE",
    "entityType": "ImageResource"
   },
   "PORTRAIT": {
    "uri": "http://www.url.com/image-file",
    "orientation": "PORTRAIT",
    "entityType": "ImageResource"
   },
   "LANDSCAPE": {
    "uri": "http://www.url.com/image-file",
    "orientation": "LANDSCAPE",
    "entityType": "ImageResource"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I need to parse out the values `SQUARE`, `PORTRAIT` and `LANDSCAPE` and their associated `uri` and `orientation` values. Then I need to be able to wrap the `uri` in an `img` tag. So far, I can just spit out the JSON structure, but not sure how to filter out the specific fields needed.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: JSON.parse then access it like any javascript object

Comment: @jfin3204 Can you clarify how to implement within the success function to loop through the entries and find/display the `orientation` and associated `uri`?

Comment: I tried `var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                        $(".response").html(obj.entity.entries);`, but this isn't working.

Comment: The answer from Hubert will work.  or you could try $.parseJSON(response.responseText)

Comment: Is this how you propose I should implement it: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/yp9k14w3/? I don't see how this would allow me to append it to the response div...

Comment: @Matt You would need to construct the html elements you wanted from the data in the response.  Then append those elements to the dom.  You are sending back JSON not HTML it will have to be converted. If you control what is being returned you could send html from the server and then just plug it into the response class, but if it is json it will have to be converted to be added to the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do more processing before you add this to the markup.  Remember these are not HTML these are JSON and when you call parseJSON on the response you will have javascript objects not HTML elements. What you want is more like

```
 var obj = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        for (var property in obj.entity.entries) {
            if (obj.entity.entries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                $(".response").append($("<img alt='test' src='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "'/>"));
            }

        }
```

And any other things you might want to add to the response.

You can add an id to each image that you add and then check to see if it already exists before appending it to the response div, or you can look at the src value  to see if it would be a duplicate.

Comment: I understand that it's returning JSON, not HTML elements. What I'm not sure about is how to implement the `.parseJSON` into my existing code, and be able to print out the resulting entities: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/nFUVs/118/

Comment: @Matt Well looking at your fiddle you are using the wrong selector, ".response" is looking for a class not an id.  Basically you want to loop through the entity's entries array and then build the html elements you want using the data that was returned.  So the code above loops through and creates an image using the uri as the src attribute and then appends that value to all elements that have a class of response.

Comment: My actual code has the correct class, that was just a typo in the example I setup. By placing the for loop in my code, it's actually breaking the app. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/nFUVs/119/

Comment: @Matt You are missing the closing curly bracket for success.

Comment: This is breaking the app: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/nFUVs/122/. What am I missing, that isn't allowing this to run properly?

Comment: @Matt WIll entries always return one object or could it return multiple? If it can return multiple then you need to make it return an array of objects.  Sorry about that.  If it will only return the one object then you can just say obj.entity.entries.SQUARE.uri etc.

Comment: At most, it will return SQUARE, PORTRAIT and LANDSCAPE. Therefore, specifying the orientation may not work. It would need to loop through them and output each one. However, there is still an issue having the for loop in the success callback. The app is not working with it there, and I'm not sure why that is, or where to put it.

Comment: @Matt updated my answer should give you what you need.

Comment: I just tried your revision, but nothing is showing in the response div or share-link div now. Updated fiddle with your revision and the full JSON structure for clarity: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/nFUVs/123/

Comment: here look at this.  I got rid of all the ajax stuff and just created a json string using your data and then processed it http://jsfiddle.net/jfin3204/1ach6h67/

Comment: thanks for the help. I had to add `var r = JSON.stringify(response);` to be able to grab the JSON correctly.

Comment: you should be able to use response in the for then. Stringify converts json to a string.  give response.entity.entries a try in the for statement.  Glad its working for you.

Comment: I'm having an issue with the first orientation coming up after each successive submission. So, if I submit a square image, then landscape, the square shows up again(meaning SQUARE SQUARE LANDSCAPE, instead of just SQUARE LANDSCAPE. How can I check to see if the previous orientation has already been shown? So I should get SQUARE LANDSCAPE PORTRAIT, and no more.

Comment: updated the answer.  If you have more questions go and start a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75866/discussion-between-matt-and-jfin3204).

Answer (score 2):

Code becomes clearer when you don't use inline functions. Let's assign a function handle to success:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: "json",
    success: myJSONsuccess;
    ...
});
```

So there must be a function named "myJSONsuccess":

```
var myJSONsuccess = function (JSONobj, StatusString, jqXHR) {
    //you probably will not need StatusString and jqXHR, so ignore them

    //There is no need to parse JSONobj. It is already parsed because of
    //dataType: "json"
    //in your ajax-command

    //This is SQUARE:
    var squ = JSONobj.entity.entries.SQUARE;

    //This is one of its properties:
    var orient = JSONobj.entity.entries.SQUARE.orientation;

    //alternatively you can write:
    var orient = squ.orientation;
    //this is exactly the same
};
```